# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'record_high'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, spyder

My Code

```
import numpy as np import pandas as pd

print('-' * 50) 
filename = r'''C:\Users\Computer\Documents\Python Scripts\weather.txt''' 
df = pd.read_csv(filename) 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
print (df.describe()) 
print (df.record_high)
```

My data

```
month, avg_high, avg_low, record_high, record_low, avg_percipitation
Jan, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.95
Feb, 61, 45, 78, 26, 3.02
Mar, 65, 48, 84, 25, 2.34
Apr, 67, 50, 92, 28, 1.02
May, 71, 53, 98, 35, 0.48
Jun, 75, 56, 107, 41, 0.11
Jul, 77, 58, 105, 44, 0.0
Aug, 77, 59, 102, 43, 0.03
Sep, 77, 57, 103, 40, 0.17
Oct, 73, 54, 96, 34, 0.81
Nov, 64, 48, 84, 30, 1.7
Dec, 58, 42, 73, 21, 2.56
```

When I run it, it gives me an error saying AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'record_high' but there clearly is that attribute. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=', ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a spacing error in your data. Try accessing the column by doing `(df[' record_high'])`.

If that is the case, run

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

after you read in `df`. You should then be able to access
`df['record_high']`